# laptop mouse problem

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, cursor

When I put any kind of pressure on my laptop, old latitude laptop, the mouse cursor flies across the screen. I'm running xp and wondering if there's something I can disable or anything.

Comment: Please clarify - do you have a seperate mouse plugged in, or are you relying on the trackpad?  If you need the trackpad, disabling it isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your bios and disable the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Or find some drivers that have an option to disable the trackpad when the mouse is plugged in.

The ones I used to use were Logitech's, but they worked on any mouse I plugged inside.

Answer (score 0):

The Latitude drivers allow you to turn off the track pad and/or the pointer stick.  This can be only when an external mouse is installed or any time.  Many options and availabkle from the Dell site.